# Regex to match group less than or equal to n times

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm basically looking for the reverse of

```
\d{n,} // matches \d n or more times
```

such that

```
\d{,3} // hypothetical syntax
```

would match

```
1
12
123
```

and not

```
1234
12345
etc.
```

The above examples aren't representative of anything I'm actually trying to match against. This is just a general question. Does something like this exist?

Comment: It's what you have (sort of) `\d{1,3}` Did you want to match non-greedy ?

Comment: @sln ah it does...my bad you initially didn't have a `1` in your comment...if you want to post this as an answer I'll accept.

Comment: All engines require the initial range quantifier, the max one is optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Engines that support the range quantifier `{min,max}`  syntax
specify that

- min is required
  ( minimum matches of the preceding construct )
- **,** is optional
  If **,** is not present, max = min
- max is optional and **,** must precede it if max is present
  ( maximum matches of the preceding construct )
  If max is not present, and is preceded by a **,**  the max defaults to unlimited.

You can't tell the range quantifier to be un-greedy.
It is always greedy, but may match less if backtracking occurs,
or it can't match the maximum, because it's not there.
Or some surrounding assert construct(s) prohibit a full max range match.

Comment: *You can't tell the range quantifier to be un-greedy*  is not true, JavaScript support lazy [limiting quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit), see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/BAc9xi/1), where the first group only takes the first 2 digits.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Right, a qualifier `?` can always apply to a quantifier. Since the range quantifier specifies a min/max, it's default state is greedy and it's primary purpose. A range qualifier, in my experience is seldom / never appropriate.